# How to make a blocked object on a div display on another?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using prototype.js function to crop a hidden img. The javascriptfunction to crop is "crop". It crops the image on body onload. The HTML div=id that will call "crop" is "crop". Also, div="thumb" is performing a specific hover different from class="top".

//*first it goes like this:

```
<div class="thumb">
<span class="text">text text text text text text text</span>
<div id="crop" class="top" style="width:900px; height:250px; /">
</div>
</div>
```

//*and here is the image to be croped:

```
<img id="img" src="bond.jpg" style="display:none" />
```

The class="thumb" with the  there makes a small box with "text text text".
Now, what is happening is, class "thumb" hovers a box with "text text" behind div="crop".

I've tried alot to try to skip the need to put the class=thumb to do that but in fact the div id="crop" doesn't work this way.

On other words, I think that since div id="crop" is already performing the function to crop the way it is coded there, it is better leave it that way

Now check the croping function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function crop(img_id, crop_id, x, y, width, height) {
$(crop_id).update('<img id="' + crop_id + '_img" src="' +
$(img_id).getAttribute('src') + '" style="display:none" />');

var scale_x = $(crop_id).getWidth() / width;
var scale_y = $(crop_id).getHeight() / height;

$(crop_id).setStyle({
position: 'relative',
overflow: 'hidden' 
});

$(crop_id + '_img').setStyle({
position: 'absolute',
display: 'block',
left: (-x * scale_x) + 'px',
top: (-y * scale_y) + 'px',
width: ($(img_id).getWidth() * scale_x) + 'px',
height: ($(img_id).getHeight() * scale_y) + 'px'
});
}
</script>
```

of wich will be called on bodyload:

```
<body onload="crop('img', 'crop', 0, 0, 1400, 300)">
```

SO afterall what I really want to ask is: how to make the "text text text" box appear in front of all div's (crop and thumbs)?

here the css used:

```
.top {  
position: absolute;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20pt;
font-weight: bold;
background:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px dashed #000000;
height: 5%;
width: 100%;
}

.thumb {
position: relative; 
width: 910px;
height: 250px;
border: 2px dashed #444;
margin: 10px;
float: left
}

.text, .text-js {
display: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #999;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
text-align: center
}
.thumb:hover .text {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ported your code to a jsFiddle. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/724Vm/) is the one that has the solution.

It's hard to tell if the crop is working properly, because we don't have the image, but I believe that giving the `<span class="text">` a high `z-index` (I used 100) fixes the problem. Now when you mouseover the div, the text appears.

CSS:

```
text, .text-js {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    z-index:100; //add this
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. Take a look at the fiddle youve created; ive updated a secound edit: http://jsfiddle.net/724Vm/2/ (if this link does not work try: "fiddlelink" + /2/") it is now working ok locally; the crop works for local image ref/src's. In fiddle it does not seem to work. Could you figure out how to make it work in your fiddle in order to share? thanks

Comment: Unless you were to upload the image in your post, I cannot create a fiddle that would display the image. If it works on your local filesystem, then great. You have the image. But unless you put the image online, then I cannot help you, as I don't have access to the image on your filesystem.

Comment: Yep that is about it: got to upload the image to the webhost, it works. Ive also tryed remote imgs, but it only works via local imgs.

Comment: Yep that is about it: the image must belong to the same host dir, it works. Ive also tryed remote imgs, but it only works via "/directory/img.jpg". May I guess it only works this way because the crop function cannot fetch img.widht and img.height of remote files?